# Switch between frames as standard (Feed/Detail)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I've created a Visualforce where with 2 Iframes and there users will be able to navigate between Chatter Feed and the Record info's itself. - They want see separately as default. Now I need create two buttons where will simulate the same feature as you know.

Then, did somebody work on something similar? I've been struggling with the js then any help it's welcome. thank you

Below a piece of code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <apex:iframe id="page1-iframe" src="Page1?Id={!SOjbect.Id}" width="100%" height="600px" scrolling="true" frameborder="false"/>
        </div>

         <div class="test">
            <apex:iframe id="page2-iframe" src="Page2?Id={!SOjbect.Id}" scrolling="true" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="false"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [apex:tabPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm) and let Salesforce take care of the JS for you:

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client">
  <apex:tab label="Feed">
    <apex:iframe ... />
  </apex:tab>
  <apex:tab label="Details">
    <apex:iframe ... />
  </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Comment: nice catch sfdcfox, I will change the css (as default) to check if they agree.
I will update the topic once I get it